# Foreach loop array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to create an array using foreach which is used inside an another array.

```
$team =  array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $team[] = array($item->post_title => $item->post_title, );
}
print_r($team);


$meta_boxes[] = array(
    'title'  => __( 'Team', 'meta-box' ),
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name'     => __( 'Select', 'meta-box' ),
            'options'  =>  $team,
        ),
    )
);
```

The options array should be in the format of

```
'options' => array(
    'value1' => ('Label1'),
    'value2' => ('Label2'),
),
```

The print_r output is

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [Jessi] => Jessi ) 
  [1] => Array ( [Adam] => Adam )
  [2] => Array ( [Babu] => Babu ) 
)
```

I am getting output as Array,Array,Array in selectbox for which I am trying to use this for. How do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Key in array `[$item->post_title]`  and assign the values

```
$team =  array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $team[$item->post_title] = $item->post_title;
}
print_r($team);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with -

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $team[$item->post_title] = $item->post_title;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try like this

```
$team =  array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $team = array_merge($team,array($item->post_title => $item->post_title));
}
```